# ZXingObjC encoding issues

Tags: ios, barcode, zxing, encoder

Been using the ZXing barcode encoder in an iOS app I'm developing. It works fine for generating any barcode format except for Code93 and UPC-E. The result it returns is null for these two formats.

Anyone else having these problems?

Thanks

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code demonstrating your issue.

Comment: Sure, I am simply using the sample code from their github repo which can be found here https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC.